# Unix execv call only occurring on first run

Tags: c, unix

I'm writing a C program that is supposed to take its command line arguments, print them, remove the two arguments on the end, and then repeat until no arguments remain. For example, calling

```
a.out alpha beta gamma delta epsilon zeta eta
```

should print the following:

```
alpha beta gamma delta epsilon zeta eta
beta gamma delta epsilon zeta
gamma delta epsilon
delta
```

The code I've come up with looks like this:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   char **ptr;

   for (ptr = argv+1; *ptr; ptr++)
      printf("%s ", *ptr);
   printf("\n");

   if (argc > 3) {
       *(ptr-1)=NULL;
       execv(*argv, argv+1);
   }
   printf("Done!");

   return 0;   
}
```

This works fine for the first exec call, but no further execs result, and the output with the given example is

```
alpha beta gamma delta epsilon zeta eta
beta gamma delta epsilon zeta
Done!
```

And I cannot figure why. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: The `exec` functions replace your process, your loop isn't going to get a chance to run more than once.

Comment: @William Well, no, you want to only `exec` in the child process only. The parent process should `wait`. If you just call `fork` without checking the return value, you'll be `exec`ing from both places. ;-)

Comment: @Chris Of course, but that's still a call to `fork` before every call to `exec`, isn't it? :)

Comment: You might want to check the return value from `execv`. Normally `execv` doesn't return.  However, an error will cause `execv` to return without launching a new instance, and that would explain the behavior that you're seeing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of the comments about calling `fork` before `execv` are nonsense.  In your case, you don't want the original process to continue beyond the point where `execv` is called, and therefore there is absolutely no reason to call `fork`.

The reason that your code doesn't work is due to the fact that the `argv` array is **not** setup correctly before calling `execv`.  Because the `argv` array is incorrect, `execv` returns an error.  Normally, `execv` doesn't return, but in the case of an error, `execv` returns and sets the `errno` which you can display with `perror`.  So you should follow the `execv` with a `perror` like so

```
 execv(*argv, argv+1);
 perror( "execv returned" );
```

Then the output from the program is

```
alpha beta gamma delta epsilon zeta eta 
beta gamma delta epsilon zeta 
execv returned: No such file or directory
Done!
```

So why does this happen? Because the first argument in the `argv` list is the name of the program itself.  This can be demonstrated by printing the entire `argv` list. Replace this line

```
for (ptr = argv+1; *ptr; ptr++)
```

with this

```
for (ptr = argv; *ptr; ptr++)
```

to print *all* of the arguments and then the output is

```
./a.out alpha beta gamma delta epsilon zeta eta 
alpha beta gamma delta epsilon zeta 
execv returned: No such file or directory
Done!
```

Notice that the first time the program is run, `argv[0]` is `./a.out`, and therefore `./a.out` is passed to `execv` as the program name.  However, the second time you call `execv`, you are passing `alpha` as the name of the program. Since `alpha` is not a valid command name (lucky for you), `execv` fails and returns an error.

To fix the problem, you need to make sure that `argv[0]` is always the name of the program. Here is the corrected code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    int i;

    for ( i = 1; i < argc; i++ )
        printf( "%s ", argv[i] );
    printf( "\n" );

    if ( argc <= 2 )
    {
        printf( "Done!\n" );
        return( EXIT_SUCCESS );
    }

    argv[argc-1] = NULL;         // drop the last argument
    argv[1] = argv[0];           // preserve the program name as the first argument

    execv( argv[0], &argv[1] );
    perror( "execv returned" );  // should never happen

    return EXIT_FAILURE;         // exec failed, return error
}
```

Comment: @pilcrow LOL sorry, I was surprised that no one beat me to it, an hour is a long time on these forums :)

Comment: Hah! Well spotted, +1!